# Limit as $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\cos(1/x)}{x-\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I've been trying to get this limit for hours. Can someone help me, please?
The solution manual says it's 0 but I can't get there. I tried to use $\lim_{h\to0} {h-\cos(h)\over h} = 0$.

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\cos(1/x)}{x-\sqrt{x}}.$$
Thank you.

Comment: Just in general, if you have a discontinuity inside of a trig function, check squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide numerator and denominator by $x$.

$$\frac{x\cos(1/x)}{x-\sqrt x}=\frac{\cos(1/x)}{1-x^{-0.5}}$$

Now see that

$$-1\le\cos(1/x)\le1$$

And apply squeeze theorem.

---

Remark:  Notice that $\frac{x\cos(1/x)}{x-\sqrt{x}}$ is not defined for $x<0$, so the above limit only makes sense as $x\to0^+$.

Comment: And what is the result ??

Comment: @Fred The one the OP's "solution manual" states.  See that $\frac1{1-x^{-0.5}}\to0$ as $x\to0^+$.

Comment: There must be a simpler way, I never talked about that theorem. (I'm learning it now, but do you know any simpler way?) Thank you though, that's really helpful.

Comment: Oh sorry, the theorem seems simple. Thank you!

Comment: @SadSeven Well, just see that $\cos(1/x)$ is a small number and that $1-x^{-0.5}\to-\infty$.  A small number divided by an arbitrarily large number is even smaller.

Answer (score 0):

> $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\cos(1/x)}{x-\sqrt{x}}.$$

Due to the $\sqrt{x}$, clearly $x>0$. Substitute $t = \frac{1}{x}$, then $t \to +\infty$ as $x \to 0^+$ and you have:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\cos\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)}{x-\sqrt{x}}
= \lim_{t\to +\infty}\frac{\tfrac{1}{t}\cos\left(t\right)}{\tfrac{1}{t}-\sqrt{\tfrac{1}{t}}}
= \lim_{t\to +\infty}\frac{\cos\left(t\right)}{1-\sqrt{t}}$$
And the limit is clearly $0$ since $-1 \le \cos t \le 1$ and the denominator is unbounded.